# NoMethodError: undefined method `detect' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an object, but I am getting a really weird error which I am not sure where is coming from or even how to debug it.

`PushNotification.new(user_id: 7, notification_type: 'foo')`

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `detect' for false:FalseClass
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:471:in `match_attribute_method?'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activemodel-4.2.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:457:in `respond_to?'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:236:in `respond_to?'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:56:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:54:in `_assign_attribute'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:41:in `block in assign_attributes'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `each'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:35:in `assign_attributes'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/core.rb:564:in `init_attributes'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/core.rb:281:in `initialize'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
from (irb):58
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

My schema is like this:

```
create_table "push_notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",           limit: 4,   null: false
  t.string   "notification_type", limit: 191, null: false
  t.datetime "created_at",                    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                    null: false
end
```

Any ideas where this might be coming from?

Comment: What does your `PushNotification` model look like?

Comment: I didn't think to look into the model. You are correct. I mistakenly used a reserved word as a function name.

Answer (score 0):

I mistakenly used a reserved word as a function name which threw this error.

To help other people who might run into this:

http://www.rubymagic.org/posts/ruby-and-rails-reserved-words

Comment: what was the word?

Comment: The reserved word was **send**

Comment: It is __not__ a reserved word in a real sense. Rather, a very important method exists with this name, and you overrode it, rendering existing functionality unavailable. But if we were to oversimplify, then yes, it's a reserved word.